# Drag and Drop empty folders with React-dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, filesystems, react-dropzone

I am working on a folder uploading project and using React-dropzone for that.

however when I drop a folder and the folder does not contain anything then acceptedFiles
stays empty.  I have noticed acceptedFiles, each file object contains a "path" attribute which gives the location, that's because react-dropzone uses the file-selector library.

`const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles) => {console.log(acceptedFiles)}`

but according to the DOC I can create a custom made drop event which can detect if a folder was dropped (even if its empty)
 `const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop, getFilesFromEvent: event => myCustomFileGetter(event)})`

Does anyone know how can I generate a path for my empty folder structure?
It's an issue because if I'm dropping a folder with multiple child folders just only those folder gets detected by file-selector which has a file in it.

Comment: have you found the solution ?

Comment: no :( let me know if u do

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the library that it uses looks for files to upload, and if there are no files in a folder, then it doesn't upload the folder. This comes from the idea that "Why would you need to upload an empty folder?" when uploading the files themselves.

This is a limitation with the file-selector library itself, so it might be a better idea to find another solution to the problem.

https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/934

Comment: any idea how to create that path for empty folders?

Comment: The file selector works by uploading files with their path, and creates the folder structure from the path. It is not able to take a path without a file with it. 

However, there might be a different solution. Why would you need to have an empty folder?

Comment: so for example If we drop a folder with multiple child folders and 1 of them doesnt contain a file in it, it wouldnt detect it,Im working on a document manager software and whenever I drop a folder the backend needs to recreate the folder structure as it was dropped, even if its empty, and that path would be the key

Comment: There would be a disconnect with what you are intending to do and the method you are accepting it, since it only accepts files themselves, and not folders.

Perhaps a better approach would be to accept a zipped file and use your backend to unzip and use that since it will hold the entire folder structure. Do you think that would work?

Comment: might be, thanks